# Version Control - Branch Trunk or Folder In Trunk?

Tags: svn, version-control

When creating a branch, is it standard practice to create a branch the trunk or is it acceptable to branch a folder/sub-folder in the trunk.

The latter seems like it would get confusing before too long...?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. That is a very SVN specific problem. Git does not have this problem. Which are you asking about? Also, if you can provide a simple illustration of the two choices you're considering that would help us answer.

Comment: I would say this is opinion-based, and that the distribution of opinions you'll hear will depend on what specific tool you're talking about.

Comment: You're right - this is SVN specific.@Schwern let's say I have an SVN repo with FolderA and FolderB.
I want to create a branch to modify the contents of FolderB. I won't be working in FolderA. 
My colleague (also new-ish to SVN) branched FolderB, instead of the trunk, which I found unusual. 
If i do a switch in FolderB to FolderB_branch there are no issues, but i can see that being confusing if there are several folders branched (how do you know where they actually belong?)

Comment: I think this answers it pretty well: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.branchmerge.switchwc.html